# Grails allow null for double not working

Tags: grails, grails-orm

the nullable is not working for lat and lng. Please help.

```
class Location {
    int id
    String country
    String province
    String city
    double lat 
    double lng 
static mapping = {
    table: 'Locaations'
    country length:100
    province length: 100
    city length: 100
}    
static constraints = {
    province(blank:true, nullable:true)
    city(blank:true, nullable:true)
    lat(blank: true, nullable:true)
    lng (blank:true, nullable:true)

}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primitive `double` type variable itself can neither be null nor be blank(`blank:true` is for String only). It has nothing to do with Grails. Use java.lang.Double instead:

```
.....
    Double lat 
    Double lng 
.....
```